# Error trying to use iterator returned from ptr_map::find

Tags: c++, boost

I am getting a compilation error on the code below. The error is:

```
/ ... /main.cpp:21:22: error: no member named 'name' in 'boost::ptr_container_detail::ref_pair<std::__1::basic_string<char>, repo *const>'
    std::cout << it->name;
                 ~~  ^
```

What am I doing wrong here? I've tried both it.name and it->name and neither works.

Regards, David.

```
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_map.hpp>

class repo {
public:
    repo(const std::string & repo_name) : name(repo_name) {}

    std::string name;
};

typedef boost::ptr_map<std::string, repo> repo_map;
repo_map repos;

int main() {
    std::string repo_name("x");

    repo_map::iterator it = repos.find(repo_name);
    if (it == repos.end()) {
        it = repos.insert(repo_name, new repo(repo_name)).first;
    }

    std::cout << it->name;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is a **ptr**_map, it returns `pair<key, ptr_value>`. So you need:

```
it->second->name
```

Comment: Thanks - it->second->name did it. I did not realise iterators were pairs, and the boost tutorial/examples don't show anything about them. I guess this is the same as a std::map so is assumed knowledge or something.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do the work

it->second.name